# Create plot of ellipses from all array values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, iteration

I want to create plot of ellipse from semi-major and semi-minor array pairs given in the code as x and y. Until now I have only been able to create a single plot from the single array value of x and y. How can I plot ellipses from all x and y values ?  [image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math as m
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1=6.5 #Approach distane measurement point
y1=0.45 #Lateral distance measurement point
Nx=np.linspace(80,60,10)
Ny=np.linspace(80,60,10)
c=20
a=(10**(Nx/c))
b=(10**(86/20))
x=x1*(a/b) #semi major axis
#rx=x*m.cos(m.radians(45))

a=(10**(Ny/c))
b=(10**(83/20))
y=y1*(a/b) #semi mionr axis
#ry=y*m.cos(m.radians(45))
resolution = 1000 
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, resolution)
xr = x[5] * np.cos(t) * np.cos(m.radians(0)) - y[5] * np.sin(t) * np.sin(m.radians(0))
yr = y[5] * np.sin(t) * np.cos(m.radians(0)) + x[5]* np.cos(t) * np.sin(m.radians(0))
plt.plot(xr, yr)
print x
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by "contours from all the values of x and y", could you clarify?

Comment: @JerryHu I have list of x and y values. I need to plot all the ellipses from  the list of x and y values in a single file.

Comment: you are just repeating yourself, it is still totally unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you create arrays of semi-major and semi-minor axes pairs, and you want to draw a contour for each pair.

In your code why are you only using x[5] and y[5] when you can simply use an index to loop over all elements?

```
for i in range(10):
    xr = x[i] * np.cos(t) * np.cos(m.radians(0)) - y[i] * np.sin(t) * np.sin(m.radians(0))
    yr = y[i] * np.sin(t) * np.cos(m.radians(0)) + x[i]* np.cos(t) * np.sin(m.radians(0))
    plt.plot(xr, yr)
plt.show()
print(x)
```